# Sorting the Data table in same Dataset using Dataviewmanager in Ado.net

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset, dataviewmanager

I'm trying to sort the data in a DataTable which is in a Dataset.

By Using the below code it is working

```
DataTable dt = (this._dataSet).Tables["Customers"];
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Surname";
dt.TableName = "Customers";
DataTable defaultviewtable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();    
(this._dataSet).Tables.Remove("Customers");
(this._dataSet).Tables.Add(defaultviewtable);
```

By using the above code sorting is working, but because of the other table relationships  it's not removing the table (from the line 5 in code) and throwing an error "Relationships should be removed first" which is not at all my case. If I remove the relationships I will loose the data from other table.

I tried by Using "DataviewManager" for sorting but it is not sorting ?

Can any one suggest how to append the sorted data to DataSet from DataViewManager ?

Note : My Dataset has 4 tables.

This is the code :

```
var dataViewSetting = new DataViewManager(this._dataSet).DataViewSettings["Customers"];

if (dataViewSetting != null)
{
    dataViewSetting.ApplyDefaultSort = true;
    dataViewSetting.Sort = "Surname";
}
```

Comment: Could you remove all rows from dt, then add them back from defaultviewtable?

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt = (this._dataSet).Tables["Customers"];
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Surname";
dt.TableName = "Customers";
DataTable defaultviewtable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();    

// Remove all rows from the table
for(int i = dt.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
}

// Add rows back using the sorted view
for(int i = 0; i < defaultviewtable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(defaultviewtable.Rows[i].ItemArray);
}
```